# is it a good way to use del and delete dataframes at the end of jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, design-patterns, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering, is it a good way to delete the data frames used in jupyter notebook at the end of it or more generally, delete variables when we are done with them(for freeing memory)?
if it is a good pattern, when we should delete them? used special cell(s) for this purpose or what?